# error : Mylyn GitHub connector not installing on eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, git

installed EGit plugin for eclipse successfully but Mylyn GitHub connector is not installing on eclipse.here i am adding the error details

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse EGit Mylyn GitHub Feature 2.3.0.201302130906 (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.201302130906)
  Missing requirement: Mylyn GitHub Connector UI 2.3.0.201302130906 (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui 2.3.0.201302130906) requires 'package org.eclipse.egit.core [2.3.0,2.4.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse EGit Mylyn GitHub Feature 2.3.0.201302130906 (org.eclipse.mylyn.github.feature.feature.group 2.3.0.201302130906)
    To: org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui [2.3.0.201302130906]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens if your eclipse version is too old, as detailled in [bug 365425](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365425)

Make sure your Eclipse is at least 3.7 or more recent.

The [latest EGit 3.0.x](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/) would require an Eclipse Kepler 4.3.

Comment: is it possible to update my eclipse or i need to download new one and install all plugins?

Comment: @Prabha don't update an Eclipse: it could break what is currently working. Simply install a newer Eclipse elsewhere, and try to add those plugin for that new instance. If that doesn't work, at least you still have your old setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,starting with new eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Happened to me yesterday because **GitHub Mylyn Connector** (http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates) was missing in Eclipse Window / Preferences / Install/Update / Available Software Sites **and** Eclipse tried to retrieve the **obsolete version 2.3.0** from another http://download.eclipse.org/??? software site (can't remember exactly), including org.eclipse.mylyn.github.ui [2.3.0.201302130906] while there already was a preinstalled 3.0.3.something version in Juno. Adding the missing Software Site allowed me to install version 3.0.3...